# dotnet.exe fails to start when restarting Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have several Azure app services live and I've ran into a consistent problem when restarting any of them.

We've right-click -> Published from Visual Studio upto an existing instance of an App Service which brings it online and functional immediately, we can update and republish new code without a problem, but restarting to app service from Azure Portal doesn't launch `dotnet.exe`.

When restarting or stopping/starting, the thread count instantly drops to 0 and continues to do nothing.

*I have to manually publish from VS again to reboot `dotnet.exe`*.

I can see that `dotnet.exe` isn't an active process via `Kudu -> Process Explorer`, and manually publishing up to the App Service and then refreshing the `Process Explorer` list again shows that `dotnet.exe` is now an active process and the App Service begins to function as expected.

Is there a way to prevent this, or at the very least debug why it's happening?

Comment: I've set up a production and staging deployment slot which is helping, but I'd still be interested to know why this has occurred.

Comment: Those are probably ASP.NET Core apps, right?

Comment: Yes they are, one is a Web API and the another is a Web App MVC. Both do exactly the same thing, so at least it's consistent. Adding in a staging slot and hot-swapping prod/staging once staging is warmed up has resolved it, but I still see 0 threads count and CPU usage on my metrics, not sure if the metrics just lag behind a little bit though.

Comment: Have a look if [installing the Site Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-preview-site-extension) helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look now!

Comment: Still not resolved, using extensions and deployment slots still makes this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out this is being caused by silent failures, outside of error handling I'd put in place. IIS would spin up the associated processes but `dotnet` would throw and error and "silently" die.

I use quotes because I'd failed to utilise Azure's indepth logging, which hid the error message from plain view until switched on.

For some basic debugging steps:

- Open up your `Kudu` console (Advanced Tools -> Go -> Debug Console) and navigate to `LogFiles`, open up `eventlog.xml`, the latest events are listed at the bottom.
- Run `dotnet myDll.dll` against your `debug` folder locally, where `myDll.dll` is the main `dll` in your project. This will typically throw the error causing `dotnet` to exit out, which wasn't obvious at design time.
- Ensure that your server-side `appsettings.json` (or the associated `appsettings.[development/release].json` contains the connection strings you're attempting to access.

The errors that were occuring we'ren't due to design-time bugs, it generally fell over when trying to access run-time resources (such as `appsettings`).